# What's the Kubernetes Client-Java API to get all deployments

Tags: java, kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

I've been exploring the [Kubernetes-Client/Java library](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java) and I can't figure out the API call to get all the deployments.

I'm looking for the K8-Client/Java API call for this command:

```
kubectl get deployments
NAME             DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
appservice1       3         3         3            3           5d
appservice2       3         3         3            3           1d
appservice3       1         1         1            1           22d
```

**More specifically, I'm interested in determining the number of desired & current pods for each deployment (like above).**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find all methods of the Kubernetes java client here:
https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/tree/master/kubernetes/docs

What you're searching for is the `listNamespacedDeployment` or `listDeploymentForAllNamespaces`.

The return type of those methods is `V1DeploymentList` so you'll find the `V1DeploymentStatus` which is containing all information about the current number of pods controlled by the deployment.

Comment: Ah I see. It's part of the `ExtensionsV1beta1Api` and I was looking at `CoreV1Api`. Thank you!

Comment: I've a follow up question: What's the difference between `ExtensionsV1beta1DeploymentStatus.availableReplicas` and `ExtensionsV1beta1DeploymentStatus.readyReplicas`? Also, is `ExtensionsV1beta1DeploymentStatus.replicas` same as `DESIRED` deployments as in my example above? Just want to clarify this a bit more.

Comment: Hi! You can refer to the following documentation file: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/AppsV1beta1DeploymentStatus.md

Comment: Page not found in answered link

Answer (score 3):

In order list some resources in kubernetes, first you must find to which apiVersion this resource type belongs to.
For deployemnts, it is `apiVersion: apps/v1`

```
AppsV1Api appsV1Api = new AppsV1Api();
appsV1Api.listNamespacedDeployment or listDeploymentForAllNamespaces
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another **[kubernetes jave client](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client)** and here is the **[example of deployments](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/examples/DeploymentExamples.java)**

Note the official library is generated by swagger and not well organized (I think).

Answer (score 0):

```
    try (KubernetesClient kubernetesClient = new KubernetesClientBuilder().withConfig(new ConfigBuilder()
            .withTrustCerts().withMasterUrl(apiUrl).withNamespace(namespace)            
            .withOauthToken(token)
            .build()).build()) {
        final OpenShiftClient openShiftClient = kubernetesClient.adapt(OpenShiftClient.class);
        System.out.println("Login Successful");

        DeploymentList dl = openShiftClient.apps().deployments().list();
        dl.getItems().forEach(System.out::println);         
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).